# Flutter: Object.fromJson() returning null

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I am using an API I made to recive some data from a json response, server sends the serializer but when trying to map such response the object returs Null

```
 Map<String, dynamic> resp = jsonDecode(response.body);
        CompanyBranch companyBranch = CompanyBranch.fromJson(resp); //this is retuning null 
        LatLng coords = LatLng(companyBranch.lat, companyBranch.lng);
        return coords;
```

This is the json response I am getting

```
{id: 1, name: Fixing Now Surcursal, outdoorNumber: 56, internalNumber: 0, street: Si, postalCode: 91193, district: No se que poner, lat: -33.3017267, lng: -66.3377522, active: true, creationDate: 2022-11-10T20:40:46.228762Z, state: 1, municipally: 1} //json response
```

This is the class CompanyBranch where it should map the response to

```
class CompanyBranch {
  int id;
  String name;
  int outdoorNumber;
  int? internalNumber;
  String street;
  int postalCode;
  String distric;
  String? state;
  String? municipality;
  double lat;
  double lng;
  bool active;
  DateTime creationDate;

  CompanyBranch(
      {required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.outdoorNumber,
      this.internalNumber,
      required this.street,
      required this.postalCode,
      required this.distric,
      required this.lat,
      required this.lng,
      required this.active,
      required this.creationDate,
      this.state,
      this.municipality,
      });

  factory CompanyBranch.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CompanyBranch(
        id: json['id'] as int ,
        name: json['name'] as String,
        outdoorNumber: json['outdoorNumber'] as int,
        internalNumber: json['internalNumber'] as int ,
        street: json['street'] as String,
        postalCode: json['postalCode'] as int,
        distric: json['district'] as String,
        lat: json['lat'] as double,
        lng: json['lng'] as double,
        active: json['active'] as bool,
        creationDate: json['creationDate'] as DateTime,
        state: json['state'] as String,
        municipality: json['municipaly'] as String,
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure `json['key']` matches json response. Add type casting to your fromJson factory like 
`id: json['id'] as String`,
`postalCode : json['postalCode'] as int`,
and so on

Comment: "municipaly" and "distric" keys are wrong. since you declared "distric" as Non-nullable type, you should provide value that is not null. Otherwise declare "distric" and nullable type with String?.

Comment: Thank you for answering I have made both changes, still marked as null